# What are the standard methods to passing state from parent to child in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've recently been coding my first React project and have consistently come across a problem. When I pass state to a child lets say in an empty-dependency useEffect, and then the state updates, the child does not update as well. I run into the same problem using useRef as well. My question is: **is there a standard method of passing information from parent to child without running into the problem of javascript closures?** Is there a way to pass a state to a component who is only interacted with once on mount and have it keep reflecting new changes?

In my problem specifically, I have a piano component with pianokey children components. I create the piano in an empty-dependency useEffect. When I want to update the pianokeys with something that doesnt need a rerender lets say information to trigger an animation, I am currently cloning the key with a different prop. This could be done with using state but closures keep bogging me down.

Code snippet:

Piano

```
let pkey_index = pkey_to_pkeyind[song[end_note_index.current]['note']['note']]
          set_piano(prev_state => {
            const keys = [...prev_state]
            keys[pkey_index] = React.cloneElement(keys[pkey_index], { pb_visual_mode: 'move_down' })
            return keys
          })
```

PianoKey

```
 if (pb_visual_mode === 'expand_down') {
      console.log(note)
      setTimeout(() => {
        audio.current.play()
      }, 2000)
      
      set_playback_visuals(prev_state => {
        set_curr_pb_anim(in_prev_state => {
          let l = [...in_prev_state]
          l[1] = true
          return l
        })
return ({...prev_state,
          [pb_counter]: (
          <div key={`${pb_counter}`} ref={ref => playback_visual_refs.current[pb_counter] = ref} className='pb-visualizer-instance'></div>
          )
        })
})
```

Currently the piano clones the element with a new prop so that only the piano key updates (the piano key and its visualization are in the same component). Then the useEffect with that dependency runs and the visualization is created. This is causing 2 renders, one for the updated prop, and 1 to create the visualization. Im asking if there is a way to combine this into 1

Comment: This post needs minimal reproductive code. <insert TOS/question guide here>

Comment: You don't "share state": if you need to pass data to a child, you set a property, and the child component will rerender with updated props. Also, _do not use useEffect for this_, the whole point of useEffect is do things that need to happen _outside_ of React's control. Passing data to a child component is literally the backbone of how React works. So it might be time to hit up the React website, and [(re)take the tutorials](https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component) that teach you the basics of how React works.

Comment: Are you just asking what *props* are in React?  It's not really clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  Please provide a [mcve] (ideally as a [React code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/328193)) which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use a Ref and Imperative Handle**

This method involves using `useRef` in the parent component to hold references to each child component and `useImperativeHandle` in the child components to expose functions that can be called directly by the parent.

- **Child Component (PianoKey):** Use `useImperativeHandle` to expose a function that can be called to trigger the animation.

```js
// PianoKey component
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';

const PianoKey = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    triggerAnimation() {
      // logic to trigger animation here
    }
  }));

  return <div>{/* key visuals */}</div>;
});
```

- **Parent Component (Piano):** Use `useRef` to keep a reference to each piano key and call the `triggerAnimation` function directly when needed.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import PianoKey from './PianoKey';

const Piano = () => {
  const pianoKeysRef = useRef([]);

  // Initialize refs for each key
  const keys = [/* array of keys info */];
  pianoKeysRef.current = keys.map(
    (key, i) => pianoKeysRef.current[i] ?? React.createRef()
  );

  // Example function to trigger animation for a specific key
  const triggerKeyAnimation = (keyIndex) => {
    pianoKeysRef.current[keyIndex].current.triggerAnimation();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {keys.map((key, index) => (
        <PianoKey key={key.id} ref={pianoKeysRef.current[index]} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Benefits of This Approach**

**No Rerenders:** This approach doesn’t cause the child components to rerender since you’re directly invoking a method on the component instance rather than changing its state or props.

**Performance:** It’s more performance-friendly for scenarios like yours where rerenders are costly due to animations.

**Considerations**

**Complexity and Reactivity:** This makes your components less reactive and more imperative, which is a shift from React’s declarative nature. It might also introduce complexity into your codebase.

**Animations Logic:** Ensure that your animation logic is well encapsulated within the `triggerAnimation` method of each `PianoKey` to avoid any side effects.

This should help you control animations in child components without unnecessary rerenders and improve the performance of your piano visualization.

Comment: My problem is with the amount of rerenders currently happening without strict mode. I have a playback mode where users can view their songs (this includes visualizations that come from top of screen). Whenever an animation needs to happen I have to rerender the key components which is lagging the window. I need a method of signaling the child without causing it to rerender and I cannot do it by passing a state.

Comment: If rerenders are causing performance issues and you need a way to signal the child components (piano keys) to trigger animations without causing a rerender. Let me edit my answer to give you a different approach you can consider